# Nautilus open text file with vim and make terminal persist after closing

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, vim

I would like to open a (text) file with Vim in nautilus. This part is easy: `Right-Click -> Open With Vim` starts a terminal with vim inside running, file open already.

When I close vim, the terminal closes too. I would like the terminal to remain open, with the working directory set to the directory the file is in.

I'm sure there is a simple way to achieve this by creating a custom bash script and adding it to the context menu (or even as the default action on <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the file is selected) but I don't know how. So, How to do this?

I am on ubuntu 18.04 but I hope it is similar for later versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but the following script does the thing you want, when put as a [Nautilus script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) under the `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
file=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | head -1)
dir=$(dirname "$file")
##zenity --info --no-wrap --no-markup --title="DEBUG" --text="$file : $dir"
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "/bin/vim \"$file\" ; cd \"$dir\" ; exec /bin/bash"
```

**Usage:** Please, add the above script contents as a new file with a meaningful name (like `VIM`) under the `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory. Then, using *Nautilus*, select a single text file, right click and on the popup menu select **Scripts** → **VIM**.

__

<sup>Disclaimer: Tested only under Ubuntu 21.10</sup>

---

If you want to insert the above functionality into the `vim.desktop` file provided by the system, you can "localize" the contents of this file by copying it to the directory `~/.local/share/applications/` and changing the line `Exec=vim %F` to call your custom shell script which can be created based on the script I provided above (Hint: Replace the line `file=…` in my script with `file="$1"` in your new script.)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. In the copy of the vim desktop file I replaced `Exec=vim %F`  with `Exec=/opt/persistentvim.sh %U` (where the bash script of yours is pasted inside, wit`file="$1"` ), and changed the name of the copied desktop file and inside gave it a different display name. Then all that remained to do was to right click my file and in the properties set the default "open with" to this version of vim. Now I can open it with doubleclick or enter, like I wanted to.